# Handling save event in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, event-handling

Good morning, I need my VBA code to run right before the TaskItem is saved, is there any way I can handle the event of saving ? I cannot find anything I could use in documentation. I am using MS-Office 2010.

Edit: I have tried

```
Private Sub TaskItem_Quit()
```

The macro disappears from macro list, but the code still does not run.

Comment: How are you saving the `Taskitem`?

Comment: By clicking the save and exit button @Om3r

Answer (score 0):

Try the Write event.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868664.aspx

"Occurs when an instance of the parent object is saved, either explicitly (for example, using the Save or SaveAs methods) or implicitly (for example, in response to a prompt when closing the item's inspector)."

Comment: In the documentation it says 2013 or later, is it possible to use this in 2010 ?

Comment: Clicking on "Other versions" gets you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868664(v=office.14).aspx Note though the example code does not appear to work. Use your own event code.